# How to tell if AOP Pointcut matches JoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, aop

What I need is a method that does this:

```
public boolean matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut, ProceedingJoinPoint);
```

i've found the method of AspectJExpressionPointcut `matches(Method, Class)` that looks like it would do the trick, and for the most part it seems to do it correctly. except when matching against bean pointcuts (`<pointcut expression="bean(beanName)" .../>`). Firstly, it returns true, even though the joinPoint has nothing to do with the bean definition. I've not tested what happens when it SHOULD match.

So maybe i should take a step back. What i'm trying to do is this:
Invoke an Advice based on several pointcuts, if the current invocation matches a subset of the list of pointcuts, perform an additional task, otherwise just continue the advice as normal.

Comment: No need for "basically" - it's a high tech "um".

Comment: The description is somewhat unclear. A (pseudo or real) code sample of what you want to achieve might be helpful. In general, if you want to intercept advice execution in AspectJ, there is a pointcut type `adviceexecution`. Maybe you want to look into that direction.